# Can I use react in place of jijnja2 in python to generate views and render it from server side?

Tags: python, reactjs, model-view-controller

Currently I have react app that is consuming rest API written in python. But I want to know whether can I use React to generate template and render it from server?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what server side framework you are using, you can build a static version of your react app and serve it from your static directory. If you peak around this github repo, you'll see it does exactly that with a Django app: https://github.com/ethankulman/react-django-boiler

To create static version of your app, you'll want to go to your react directory and use the command

```
npm run build
```

You'll see a new folder in your directory named "build" and it contains all the necessary files to serve your app statically.